# Spotify FB Login with preview api

Tags: facebook, spotify

Anyone knows how the facebook login works with the new preview spotify apps api?

I tried something like this...

```
require(['$api/facebook'], function(facebook) {
    facebook.session.showConnectui();
}
```

but nothing got me to the result I got with the old api. I also tried to use plain FB js sdk, but the problem is it needs some "url" to allow connections...wich I can't really give out of the spotify app?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `auth` module was not present at first, but now it is part of the Spotify Apps API. You can read more about it on [its documentation page](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-auth-auth.html). It looks like this:

```js
  require(['$api/auth#Auth'], function(Auth) {
    var appId = '<your_app_id>',
        permissions = ['user_about_me'];

    var auth = new Auth();
    auth.authenticateWithFacebook(appId, permissions)
      .done(function(params) {
        if (params.accessToken) {
          console.log('Your access token: ' + params.accessToken);
        } else {
          console.log('No access token returned');
        }
      }).fail(function(req, error) {
          console.error('The Auth request failed with error: ' + error);
      });
    }
  });
```

In addition, there is [a working example](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/facebook/authenticate.html) in the [Tutorial App on GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial).